# SSIS Visual Studio Executing Different Packages when Clicking Start Button

Tags: ssis

Here is the problem I have been having for years as a serious annoyance, but have seen zero information related to on the web.

1. Open an SSIS solution in Visual Studio which has several dtsx packages.
2. Open a singular package
3. Click the "Run" button to run said SSIS dtsx package in Visual studio, watching the control flow, etc.
4. Visual Studio opens other packages and runs them instead.

Anyone have a reason for this insanity?

Has happened in Visual Studio version 2013 and 2015. Can't remember if it occurred before these versions. Haven't experimented with 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy any components from other packages? If so you might be having GUID conflicts. BIDSHelper has an option to reset the GUIDs for SSIS packages that might resolve the issue.